# How to use Cleanup in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have the below code, where it pull all data from server as API

```
  export const apiExpenses = () => {

    //Get All Expenses, Realtime
    const { data: tableDataExpenses, error, mutate } = useSWR('/api/expenses/datatable', () =>
      axios
          .get('/api/expenses/datatable')
          .then(res => res.data),        
    )

    return {
        tableDataExpenses,
      }

  }
```

And using the output of that API in another component with useEffect

```
const { tableDataExpenses } = apiExpenses();
const [expenses, setExpenses] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    setExpenses(tableDataExpenses.data);

    return () => {
      setExpenses([]);
    };
  }, [tableDataExpenses]);
```

But I am ending in below errors,

```
 Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

And because of this, I can't get the value of `tableDataExpenses`

If I remove `setExpenses` from useEffect there are no errors and again if I write `setExpenses` it loads data.

But again in the next render, it fails with error.

So How can I prevent this error with the cleanup function?

Comment: You don't need to clean up state variables on unmounting components. They're more useful for things like removing event listeners, which are manually attached to the DOM and so aren't cleaned up by React

Comment: *"And because of this, I can't get the value of `tableDataExpenses`"* No, that's not why. Where can't you get it, and what does your code trying to get it look like?

Comment: I notice that you return `res.data` from your `useSWR` callback, and that you store `data` as `tableDataExpenses` when destructuring, then return that as a property in an object. But later you use `tableDataExpenses.data`. I suspect you don't want `.data` there.

Comment: @Tom, can you help why console show error of ``` cant update state....``` when using state update in useEffect? If i comment setState it load page and if uncomment it again, page load with correct data. And in immediately in next load it throw error.

Comment: @rjcode The error message gives a helpful indicator of what you need to do. It says cancel all asynchronous tasks (setState is asynchronous) in a useEffect cleanup function. You need to remove the last 3 lines of your useEffect hook

Comment: The first load won't call useEffect, because the hook only fires when one of its dependencies changes. The cleanup function (as I understand it) runs after the dependency changes but before the main code inside the hook does.